# Cannot resolve symbol '@string/default_notification_channel_id' even after adding string.xml in res/values

Tags: android, xml, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging for my current flutter project.

For setting the 'default notification channel id' variable I followed the following steps :

1. **Added strings.xml in res/value folder** :

[image]

2. **Define the variable in strings.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <string name="default_notification_channel_id" translatable="false">Channel ID</string>
</resources>
```

3. **Add that in AndroidManifest.xml** :

[image]

The issue I'm facing is that even after adding the variable definition in 'res/value/strings.xml', I am still getting an error on the variable in Android Manifest (As seen in the above screenshot highlighted in red).
The error say : "Cannot resolve symbol '@string/default_notification_channel_id' ".

I am not getting where I am going wrong in this one. Can someone please help me solving this issue.

Thanks a lot in advance for helping.

Comment: Try file->invalidate caches/restart

Comment: I tried it ...... still giving the same error

Comment: Did you check with file explorer that the file is really there? Sometimes your IDE can play with you...

Comment: @GaspardMerten Yes I just checked...... strings.xml there in res folder.

Comment: I suppose you tried flutter clean?

Comment: @GaspardMerten Yes I tried. Didnt work